# MSVC 2010 project-wide macro with parameters

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio project for code that contains

```
DL_EXPORT(void) initlua(void);
```

So I basically need a macro like

```
#define DL_EXPORT(retVal) __declspec(dllexport) retVal
```

Which works, but is OS/Compiler-specific, so I want to put that in the project*. But I can't figure out what to put in *Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions* (or in the Command Line) to do that. I'd think either of these would work:

```
DL_EXPORT(retVal) __declspec(dllexport) retVal
DL_EXPORT(retVal)=__declspec(dllexport) retVal
```

I'm leaning towards the latter, but neither seems to work - when compiling I get these errors:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'initlua'
error C2059: syntax error : ';'
error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

And compiling with /P to get the preprocessor result explains why: Nothing happened, so the compiler interpreted it as `int DL_EXPORT(void)` and expects a `;`.

What is the right syntax for the definition? Or is there none, as people in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944168/visual-c-2010-solution-wide-macros-with-parameters) assumed?

Thanks.

* I'm not using a simple #ifdef-check for MSVC because I'm just trying to create a Visual Studio project for an existing library (lunatic python) with existing build scripts that I don't want to break. Although I could admittedly use `#ifndef DL_EXPORT` - but I'd still like to know if I'm missing something or if this is just impossible to do in Visual Studio.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to define a function-like macro on cl's command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be possible to use [/FI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the commandline to specify an include file to include automatically in every source file. In that file you put the `#define` statements you need.

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround I'm currently using. Just wondering if it's possible with /D, too.